# sed/awk - How to remove lines with less than 3 columns

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Really simple question. I simply need to remove lines from a list when there are less than 3 columns

Eg:

```
a b c
a b      <--- This one needs to disappear
a b c
```

I'm pretty sure awk NF does it, however I can't seem to get it right.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

sed, grep, awk all can do this job. since you prefer awk, see if this helps?

```
awk 'NF>=3' file
```